# How to stop a workflow immediately when a session fails?

Tags: unix, informatica, informatica-powercenter

> I have a workflow that has many sessions that run in parallel to each other. When one of the session fails, the workflow waits for the other session to complete and then the entire workflow gets failed. We have selected the option **"fail parent if this task fails"**. But we want the workflow to fail and stop immediately if any of the session fails without waiting for other sessions to finish.

> ps: We have a **unix shell script** that calls all the workflows one by one. So if we can solve it using unix shell scripting that would be fine aswell.

> *Does anyone have any solution for  it*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing you can do in Informatica is use a `Control Task` to `Abort` the worklfow, and have it connected from all sessions with an `OR` condition. Something like:

```
start--S1--S2--S3
         \   \   \
          \---\---\-(OR)-CTL
```